# await does not seem to wait

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have:

```
async void getData()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start");
    HttpClient api = new HttpClient();
    await api.PostAsync("http://....",  someContent).ContinueWith(
         ....
    );
    Console.WriteLine("End");
}

void main()
{
    Task task = new Task(getData);
    task.Start();
    task.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Returned");
}
```

I consistently get the following output:

```
Start
Returned
End
```

How is it possible that the end of the getData method is executed after control has returned to the calling method?

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
async void getData()
```

to

```
async Task getData()
```

The only place you should be using `async void` is for event handlers like button click in a WPF app. The reason not to use it is because you need to return something that can be awaited and returning void effectively negates that.

Also there is no need to create a new Task. You could rewrite this as follows:

```
void main()
{
    Task task = getData();
    task.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Returned");
}
```

Comment: Might want to explain what `async void` is doing here

Comment: Still won't work right, because he is doing a `new Task(getData)` he needs to call `.Unwrap().Wait()` or  use Task.Run

Comment: Just dont use async void. nuff said. Unless events..

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - I was still editing / add to my answer :) (*typing as your comment appeared*), I had omitted the `Unwrap()` but added it now. Thanks.

Comment: *The only place you should be using async void is for WPF/WinForm event handlers* what about ASP.NET event handlers? does they not qualify?

Comment: @Rahul - I updated my answer to make it more generic. I thought it was safe to return `Task` from an asp.net event handler though, maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @OldGeezer - see the code sample I added above for the `Main` method. That in combination with the changed signature should produce the desired result.

Comment: @Igor, when I used your method of starting the task, it hung after `api.PostAsync` completes.  `End` and `Returned` are not printed.

Comment: it's actually for any event handlers .. need not be necessarily for WPF only